# URL encoded ASCII characters in a path

Tags: python, http, url

Recently I ran into a situation that left me completely confused about when/if URL encoding should be performed and why.

In general, any tutorial about URL encoding will tell you that either

1. non-ASCII characters in a URL path should be percent-encoded,
2. that certain reserved characters (like a `"?"` in a path or string query) need to be encoded in certain contexts to avoid confusion.

Okay, I get the general idea.  But recently, I ran into an issue when programatically downloading some jpeg files from an RSS feed using a Python HTTP client.  The problem started when one of the JPEG files strangely appeared as a very small (~800 byte) blank box, instead of the expected image.  The image displayed correctly in a browser, so something must have been going wrong with the HTTP request.

After going through the issue step by step, and mimicking the exact headers and everything that the browser was using, the server *still* kept returning an incorrect jpeg file.  I was so confused, I was at the point where I thought the server might be somehow treating my IP differently or whatever.

Anyway, finally I noticed the issue - the path had an encoded underscore character in it, like:

```
http://www.example.com//2675898%5fsmall.jpg
```

When pasting that into a browser window, the browser automatically percent-decoded the `%5f` into an underscore character.  When I did the same with my Python-based http client, everything worked fine.

But I'm still confused as to *why* this works, and what rules I really need to be following here.  So, the percent-encoded URL was found in an XML rss document.  I don't know *why* exactly the underscore was percent encoded, but my guess is that they simply percented encoded the URL since it appeared inside an XML attribute, and therefore they needed to make sure that certain characters like `"&"` and other reserved XML characters didn't appear.  An underscore, in particular, is harmless, but their percent encoding software probably just has a list of reserved characters it uses, which includes underscore.

Okay, so clearly the *browser* (or at least, Chrome) has built-in logic to automatically *percent-decode* a URL before sending it to the web server.

So is *that* the rule?  You should always *percent-decode* a URL before sending it to a web server?  Because that seems to contradict what a lot of online tutorials are saying, which is that you should actually always *percent-ENcode* a non-ASCII URL-path *before* sending it over the Internet.

So ... is the rule that we should always *percent-ENcode* non-ASCII characters before sending them over the Internet AND ALSO *percent-DEcode* any encoded ASCII characters (that aren't special URL characters, like a "?" in a query string).

All of that seems like a lot of logic and processing of a URL before sending it over the wire.  Is that what's necessary here?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Does the server actually have two files, one with underscore in the name and the other with literal `%5f` in the name?

Comment: It should be safe to percent-encode any character -- the server will automatically decode it when processing the URL. You only **need** to encode special characters, to prevent them from being recognized by the URL parser (like `?` separating the path from the query string).

Comment: Are you sure your URL is not *doubly* encoded? The web server should be perfectly content with the path element being either `2675898%5fsmall.jpg` or `2675898_small.jpg`. But `2675898%255fsmall.jpg` could well be an invalid path.